# Concise way to reference many columns matching regex, within a model formula

Tags: r, formula

In certain datasets I have a large number of related variables which I want to use within a model such as lm, randomforest, xgboost etc. It is not viable to type all these out manually, but I can identify the columns with regex match based on a common prefix, e.g. *'fruit_'*.

I want to construct a formula with many terms along the lines of

```
outcome ~ fruit_banana + fruit_apple + fruit_pear + ....
```

However, to reference these in a formula is more complicated than I would expect. I have a method which works, but it is feels cumbersome and I am wondering if there is a more concise method.

Note, I am looking for a solution which doesn't involve manipulating the data frame itself, since in real cases I often want to add or drop other variables to the model quickly. Secondly, I do not want to reference columns by position, as this would not be reliable.

**Example**

In the dataset below I have one variable named *'outcome'* which I wish to predict using 20 variables all begining with 'a_', and I want to ignore the other 10 columns.

Create toy dataset:

```
df = data.frame(outcome = rnorm(100), matrix(rbinom(30*100, 1, 0.2), ncol = 30))
colnames(df)[2:21] = paste0('a_', 1:20)
```

My current method to construct the formula:

```
frm = as.formula(paste0("outcome ~ ",
    paste(colnames(df)[grep('a_', colnames(df))], collapse = ' + ')))
lm(frm, data = df)
```